# Sending data to express server using react.js front-end in debugger

Tags: reactjs

I know express, react.js, but don't know how to send data from front-end to the back-end in console

Comment: why do u want to send data to server via console?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask